# Passing variables from one view to an other 

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I know this question as been asked over and over but it's still quite obscure to me, so I guess making an example with my code instead will probably be easier .

I know that you can use :

- A global variable, ( not good practice ).
- Use a delegate
- Use a singleton

Say I've got this piece of code here in my first view controller header :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UITextField *Te;
NSInteger evTe;
}


@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *Te;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger evTe;


- (IBAction) makeKeyboardGoAway;

@end
```

and then this in my implementation file

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"


@implementation FirstViewController

@synthesize Te;

- (IBAction) makeKeyboardGoAway;
{
    [Te resignFirstResponder];  
    evTe = [Te.text intValue];
}
```

How would I call ***evTe*** in my SecondViewController ? ( maybe using a delegate ?) .

This is what I've got in the second view Controller, header :

```
@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController {


        NSInteger evTe;

}



@property (nonatomic) NSInteger evTe;
```

and implementation :

```
- (IBAction) makeKeyboardGoAway;
{



    FirstViewController *first = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];
    first.evTe = self.evTe;

    NSLog(@"second value is %i",evTe);

}
```

Thanks a lot !

---

**Edit for Tob**

FirstViewController.m

```
- (IBAction) makeKeyboardGoAway;
{
    evTe = [Te.text intValue];
    NSLog(@"The value of integer num is %i", evTe);

    NSDictionary *changedValues = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:evTe] forKey:@"evTe"];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"evTeChanged" object:self userInfo:changedValues];


}
```

SecondViewController.m

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(methodToCall:) name:@"evTeChanged" object:nil];

 }

- (void)methodToCall:(NSNotification *)aNotification{

    NSDictionary *changedValues = [[aNotification userInfo]  objectForKey:@"evTe"];               
    NSString *dictionaryString = [changedValues description];
    NSLog(@"Notification returning %d",dictionaryString);

}
```

Unfortunately I'm not getting any log from the SecondView ..

Comment: NSDictionary *changedValues = [aNotification userInfo];  
NSNumber *evTe = [changedValues objectForKey:@"evTe"];               
NSLog(@"Notification returning %d",[evTe intValue]);

And has the second view controller loaded its view when you dismiss the keyboard in the first view controller?

Comment: Sorry but I thought FirstViewController created the second one? Is it Second creating first?

Comment: Ah ! that's probably what I`m doing wrong .
I'm using the tab bar template, so I`ve got 2 view controllers but I don't think Second view controller is actually already loaded when I`m dismissing the keyboard in the First view ..
Any why to preload the other view controller ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By creating a @property called evTe or whatever in both view controllers.

If the FirstViewController is responsible for creating the SecondViewController you could store the value of evTe in a property in FirstViewController and then after you have created the SecondViewController you set the evTe property there as well.

```
- (IBAction) makeKeyboardGoAway;
{
    [Te resignFirstResponder];  
    self.evTe = [Te.text integerValue];
}
```

// other method where SecondViewController is created

```
SecondViewController* second = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
second.evTe = self.evTe;
// do what ever
```

--Edit--

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UITextField *Te;
    NSInteger evTe;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *Te;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger evTe;
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the help, I`m not quite there yet, I`m getting this warning : 

Passing argument 1 of 'setevTe:' makes pointer from integer without a cast .

Then it crashes :) But the rest looks sane .

Thanks !

Comment: How did you declare the evTe property? :)

Comment: probably like a noob ? :


@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *evTe;

Comment: Hold on, I thought evTe was an int property? :)

Comment: yes, of course, sorry was distracted, I`ve switched it to :


@property int *evTe;

But I`m still getting the value at 0, could it be because I`m instanciating a new variable therefore defaulting to 0 instead of returning the value in FirstViewController ?

Comment: We need to crack this. I've updated my example to how it should look, you need the evTe property in both controllers. I've changed from intValue to integerValue, mostly because I am not sure how to deal with ints in objective-c :(

Comment: It's not crashing anymore, but the value I`m getting from the secondViewController is still zero unfortunately .

Here is how it looks now, I`ve edited the original post, no issues compiling, no warning, if I print the evTe value from the firstViewController I get something meaningful but still 0 from the secondViewController . Isn`t it because we are instantiating a new variable therefore it's set to 0 by default ?

Comment: Are you creating SecondViewController before makeKeyboardGoAway is called?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `NSNotification`. You should send a notification that the particular value has changed and register for that notification in the second view controller.

```
- (IBAction) makeKeyboardGoAway;
{
    [Te resignFirstResponder];  
    evTe = [Te.text intValue];

    NSDictionary *changedValues = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:evTe] forKey:@"evTe"];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"evTeChanged" object:self userInfo:changedValues];

}
```

And in the `viewDidLoad` method of the other controller do:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(methodToCall:) name:@"evTeChanged" object:nil];
```

Now every time the first controller calls `makeKeyboardGoAway` the method `- (void)methodToCall:(NSNotification *)aNotification` will be called.

Implement this method and ask the `aNotification` for its `userInfo` which is the `NSDictionary` you created in the first controller before posting the notification. Get the `evTe` value out of it and do whatever you want to do with that value.

Comment: I'm sure this is also a correct way to go, but if you had 1 mn to give me an example that would be helpful, I find the documentation quite cryptic on this subject ..

Comment: Hey Tob, thanks for your help.
I've implemented ( in my secondViewController.m ):

- (void)methodToCall:(NSNotification *)aNotification{
 
 NSDictionary *changedValues = [[aNotification userInfo]  objectForKey:@"evTe"];               
 NSString *dictionaryString = [changedValues description];
 NSLog(@"Notification returning %d",dictionaryString);
 
}

But I don't get any log in my terminal, which leads me to think that the methodToCall function is not being executed .
Do you see anything obviously wrong in the way I`m implementing this function ?

Comment: Did you register for the notification in viewDidLoad?

Comment: No, I didn`t I guess I should read the doc more when it comes to NSNotifications ..

Comment: Your talking about the ViewDidLoad of the SecondViewController, right ? if so, yes I`ve got :

[super viewDidLoad];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(methodToCall:) name:@"evTeChanged" object:nil];

Comment: And did you initialize the controller before makeKeyboardGoAway is called in the first controller?