# How to pass change the value of a variable in another view(objective c)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

i have two controller

in view1.h  i have

```
NSString *bg;
@interface Lottery5ViewController : UIViewController {...}
```

in view2.m i have

```
-(IBAction) switchView2{
self.bg = @"blueButton.png";
}
```

but it cannot compile and said
request for member 'bg' in something not a structure or union

i just want to modify the value of a variable in view1  from view2

Comment: Did you setup "bg" as a property and synthesize it?

Comment: yes,@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *bg ; in view1.h
and  @synthesize bg;  in view1.m

Comment: all I want is
view1 has a textview...view2 has a textfield..
user type sth in view2...then switch back to view1..The text will appear in view1

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing variables from one view to an other .](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545597/passing-variables-from-one-view-to-an-other)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that in `view2`'s `switchView2` method you are calling `self` and trying to change an ivar (or property, not sure which it is from the code shown) of a *different* class. If you want to send something from one instance to another you have to establish some sort of connection between them first. There are a few ways you can get them talking. The better ways to be able to pass something like this is to set up a delegate protocol or use notifications, then `view2` could call the delegate method that makes the change in `view1` or post a notification that `view1` would be registered for so that it could make the change. The less desirable way to accomplish this would be to give `view2` an ivar (or property) that is `view1`. You would then be able to use something like `view1.bg = @"blueButton.png";`.