# is it possible use temporary variable pass value

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have temporary variable `eneity` and two ViewController:**OneViewController** and **SecondViewController**.they jump to each other fine.now use `eneity` to send value from **OneViewController** to **SecondViewController**.But when SecondViewController return value with `eneity`, OneViewController can't get the return value anymore.

I want to know if i can use variable to get return value ,instead of delegate?

thanks for your help;

ADD:

**firstViewController,Example3ViewController**:

```
#import "Example3ViewController.h"

@interface Example3ViewController ()

@end

@implementation Example3ViewController
@synthesize editorVC;
@synthesize labelname;
@synthesize labelnumber;
@synthesize labelsummary;
@synthesize b;

(id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
// Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

(void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
//when IBOutlet not be used,use program to makd connection
EditorViewController* vc = [[EditorViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"EditorViewController" bundle:nil];
self.editorVC = vc;
vc = nil;
}

(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
NSLog(@"%@",self.b.name);
self.labelname.text = self.b.name;
self.labelnumber.text = self.b.number;
self.labelsummary.text = self.b.summary;
}

(void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

(IBAction)edit:(id)sender{
[self presentModalViewController:editorVC animated:YES];
}

@end
```

**secondeViewController,EditorViewController**:

```
#import "EditorViewController.h"
#import "Example3ViewController.h"
#import "test.h"

@interface EditorViewController ()

@end

@implementation EditorViewController
@synthesize vtitle;
@synthesize number;
@synthesize summary;

(id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
// Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

(void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

(void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

(IBAction)done:(id)sender{
//[[self parentViewController]dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
//Example3ViewController* e3v = [[Example3ViewController alloc]init];]

//e3v.name = title.text;
//e3v.number = number.text;
//e3v.summary = summary.text;
//[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^(void){

//}];
test* t = [[test alloc]init];
t.name = self.vtitle.text;
t.number = self.number.text;
t.summary = self.summary.text;
//[t setName:vtitle.text];
//[t setNumber:number.text];
//[t setSummary:summary.text];
Example3ViewController* e3v = [[Example3ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Example3ViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
e3v.b = t;

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
[t release];
[e3v release];

}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
[vtitle resignFirstResponder];
[number resignFirstResponder];
[summary resignFirstResponder];
}
@end
```

**temporary variable**:

```
#import "test.h"

@implementation test
@synthesize name;
@synthesize number;
@synthesize summary;
@end
```

Comment: Can you please show your code?

Comment: are you poping the view from second to first viewController?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545597/passing-variables-from-one-view-to-an-other?rq=1

Comment: if you using `popViewController` to come back from `SecondViewController` to `OneViewController` then you can not pass it  with `OneViewController`'s object. Show your code.

Comment: code please? Where have you declared `eneity` ? And what do you mean by saying it temporary? What I understand is temporary are only those variables whose scope is really really narrowed.

Comment: Have put my code on:)@user0000001

Comment: @Piyush have put my code on

Answer (score 0):

you can't write

```
Example3ViewController* e3v = [[Example3ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Example3ViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
e3v.b = t;
```

This will create another object of class Example3ViewController and assign t value to that object not to the object that is already in your stack.

You can either write like

```
Example3ViewController* e3v = [((AppDelegate *)[AppDelegate sharedInstance]).navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:[((AppDelegate *)[AppDelegate sharedInstance]).navigationController.viewControllers count]-1];
```

or

you can assign a `Example3ViewController` variable in `SecondViewController` (say `examplobj`)and in `viewDidLoad` of `Example3ViewController` write `vc.examplobj = self`.